# How to locate a certain series of assembly instruction within a period of time?

Tags: c++, memory, reverse-engineering

Suppose I'm observing the memory of an application(e.g. Calculator) and I want to find out a series of instructions being called within a period of time, say, 10:20 AM - 10:21 AM 25/08/14.
At 10:20 AM, I should be pressing the button of execution(geting the result of computation).
And I want to find out all the associated instructions and memory calls in the execution process.

I know I can do this in a simply way like by iterative searching for input values on the calculator. However, in other cases it becomes difficult to search for the corresponding value due to complex layers of pointers.

My question:
Is it possible to implement this(finding out instructions or calls within a period of time) in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try start with using [statistical profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29#Statistical_profilers). If the execution is question is not a short moment, and takes at least a few statistical timer periods, you'll get enough to dig into. Multiple starts will increase result accuracy.